# How can I run JVM, SDK and eclipse for Android development from portable drive?

Tags: android, jvm, adt

My PC configuration doesn't meet the requirement of Android Studio so I was thinking about running the JVM and ADT(SDK and eclipse) both from a portable device like a pen drive or a portable hard drive for android development.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here, because it is not a clear programming question, but asks for a software solution. I would suggest to re-ask it on http://superuser.com, which site is exactly for question such as this for.

Answer (score 1):

You can install JDK,  Android Studio or Eclipse onto a removable or flash drive by just copying their respective folders from your PC to the flash drive.  But then you'll have to set path for Java compiler everytime you use the flash drive on a PC.  But you'd still need the JRE on the target system.

Comment: thanks. can you pleas tell me what do you mean by target system?

Comment: The system you'd want to use as your development machine